# Reference dnx as a nuget package

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying reference to dnx as a nuget package.
To do this i include dnx-clr-win-x64 and dnx-clr-win-x86 packages in my project.json.

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "dnx-clr-win-x64": "1.0.0-beta4",
  "dnx-clr-win-x86": "1.0.0-beta4"
}
```

And set runtime-path setting in my web.confing to packages directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    ...
    <add key="runtime-path" value="../../packages" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

In my packages directory i have `dnx-clr-win-x64` and `dnx-clr-win-x86` directories with `1.0.0-beta4` subdirectories.

But when i'm trying to run my application i'm getting an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'dnx.clr.managed' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

It seems that AspNet.Loader.dll search directory named `dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta4`. But package stored in `dnx-clr-win-x64/1.0.0-beta4`.

If i create directory `dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta4` inside `packages` directory and copy `dnx-clr-win-x64/1.0.0-beta4` into it all works great.

Is it possible to reference dnx as a nuget package?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able not to install dnx in %USERPROFILE%\.dnx directory to be able to run my application on developer machine.
I want to another developer could just get sources from VCS and build it.
Now i store dnx in "runtimes" directory under VCS and reference to that directory from web.config by "runtime-path" setting.

Comment: you should write a build script then. an `ASP.NEt 5` application cannot run without `'dnx`

Comment: Yes, i can write a build script or just stay with storing DNX under VCS. But i was curious about if it possible to reference DNX as a nuget package. The only thing not working is that nuget stores packages as {PackageName}\{PackageVersion} but AspNet.Loader.dll looks for {PackageName}.{PackageVersion}.

Comment: Yes, ASP.NET 5 application cannot run without DNX but it's not necesary that DNX will be in %USERPROFILE%\.dnx directory. For example i store it in my solution directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question and your comments to it, the answer is no. You cannot reference DNX and pull it as NuGet reference because you have a bootstrapping problem: you need dnu (which is part of dnx) to download NuGet packages.

However, you can write a build script, similar to what we (the asp.net team) do: https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/build.cmd

Basically, all you build script has to do in order to acquire dnx is:

1. Get dnvm
2. Call `dnvm install <version>`

Also, if you don't want dnx globally, you can set the `DNX_HOME` environment variable to point to a different folder.